# getting every 3rd element & looping back (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function that returns every nth element of a given list but then updates the head to the second element and does this again until it has gone through all elements in the list. 
I know the code for going through every nth element in a list is:

```
everyf n [] = []
everyf n as  = head as : everyf n (drop n as)
```

but this does not loop back. How can I get this to update head so that i get the following result:

```
everyf 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
returns [[1,4,7],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

Comment: `[everyf 3 xs, everyf 3 (tail xs), everyf 3 (drop 2 xs)]`? Which generalization looks like `[everyf 3 (drop 0 xs), everyf 3 (drop 1 xs), everyf 3 (drop 2 xs)]`

Comment: @zerkms sorry for being unclear, but i want this to work for any nth element, not just 3. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know haskell (at all) :-)

```
listOfNths :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
listOfNths n xs = map (\x -> everyf n (drop x xs)) [0..n-1]
```

and a slightly "improved" version:

```
listOfNths :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
listOfNths n xs = map pickEveryf [0..n-1]
    where pickEveryf = (everyf n) . (`drop` xs)
```

Comment: well... nice try but this gives:  [[3,6],[3,6],[3,6],[3,6]]